# Why do I have to get this error so often?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

**Hello World!**

I have a small issue and I don't know how to solve it. I tried some things but nothing worked. The error looks like this:

> Undefined variable: post (View: ../resources/views/blog/posts/index.blade.php)

This is my code in the controller:

```
<?php

public function index() {
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','ASC')->paginate(15);
    return view('blog.posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
}

public function post($slug) {

    // Fetch from the database based on slug.
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // Return the view and pass the post object.
    return view('blog.posts.post')->withPost($post);
}
```

And that's a part of the code for view:

```html
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container" id="load-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      @foreach($posts as $post)
      <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="{{ url('blog/posts/'.$post->slug) }}" role="button">
          <h2 class="post-title">
            {{ $post->title }}
          </h2>
          <h3 class="post-subtitle">
            {{ $post->desc }}
          </h3>
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta">Posted on {{ date('F j, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</p>
      </div>
      <hr> @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also the route:

```
Route::prefix('/blog/posts')->group(function () {

Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index')->name('posts'); });
```

*Thank you for your answers!*

Comment: unless you are trying to use `$post` outside the `foreach` you should not be getting that error, assuming this is the code throwing the error

Comment: change this in your controller `return view('blog.posts.index', compact('posts'));`

Comment: @lagbox you were right. I was using `$post` outside the `foreach()`.

Comment: if the loop runs (there are records to iterate) there will be a `$post` variable available as the loop defines it, but if there are no records (nothing to iterate) the `$post` variable will never be defined ... best to not rely on the variable you are defining for the foreach outside the loop directly

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has two main ways of sending data (variables) from the Controller to the View. The first way, as outlined in their documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) is by chaining **with** to the view function.

```
return view('blog.posts.post')->with('post', $post);
```

You can chain **with** as much as you want, however this isn't very clean if you need to send lots of variables to the view. The more accepted way to do this is by using PHP's **compact** function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) as the second parameter of the **view** function, as @Ben96 pointed out. **compact** essentially converts a string of variable names to an associative array with their keys and values, which allows them to be used in the view.